# Add a text field on button click, that can also be saved into core data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

Okay so I've been stuck on this for quite a while, and that may be because I'm pretty new to Swift and iOS in general. But what I'm trying to do is make it so when I click a button another text field will come up, and the user will be able to type stuff into it, then save that data into Core Data.

For example, I have a Dog Names application, and I have one text field already there for the user to type there Dog's name into, but then there is a button that says "Add another name?" and when they click that, a text field shows up, and can be saved into Core Data.

I'm not asking for the code for this or what not, just a direction or link or answer of how I can go about this. This feature is very important for my application, and I would really appreciate any help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an `activeTextField` variable that tracks which is the current 'name' field being used.  You would be able to set this in the text field delegate `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method by stating `activeTextField = textField`

Then whatever button you are using to invoke some 'save' method, read the `activeTextField.text` property and save that as a new 'dog' entity or 'name' property or however you might have it set up.

You would likely want to set the `activeTextField` to `nil` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`

Comment: Well the thing is I'm actually wanting to save multiple "dog" names. So I need all of the text fields to be active, but I can't just assume how many dog names the person is going to need, hence for the button to add more text fields to the persons liking.

Comment: You could use my method to add the names one at a time, each time adding a new name to a set of names for the dog entity.  Or if you just want one save action for all text fields, then you need another way to mark which textfields for your save property to read from, like subclassing the textfields or making them with a special tag, or adding them all to some array.  You were looking for a general answer.  There's too many ways to solve this.  You'll need to pick one then post specific questions as you try to implement it.  I can help.